# Table doesn't fit with title in just one page

Tags: tables

I want a chapter tittle and a table to fit in just one page. It looks possible as it is enough space, but this is the output:

[image]

The code used is:

```
\afterpage{
\chapter{Esquemáticos y PCB}
\clearpage     % flush out other floats waiting to be typeset
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{10cm}@{}}
\toprule
Nº referencia & Descripción \\
\cmidrule(l){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
3113067-01 & Esquemático del primer prototipo de placa (página 1)\\
3113067-02 & Esquemático del primer prototipo de placa (página 2)\\
3113067-03 & Esquemático del primer prototipo de placa (página 3)\\
3113067-04 & Cara TOP de la PCB del primer prototipo de placa\\
3113067-05 & Cara BOTTOM de la PCB del primer prototipo de placa\\
3113067-06 & Vías de la PCB del primer prototipo de placa\\    
3113067-07 & Esquemático del diseño final de placa (página 1)\\
3113067-08 & Esquemático del diseño final de placa (página 2)\\
3113067-09 & Esquemático del diseño final de placa (página 3)\\
3113067-10 & Cara TOP de la PCB del diseño final de placa\\
3113067-11 & Cara BOTTOM de la PCB del diseño final de placa\\
3113067-12 & Vías de la PCB del diseño final de placa\\    
3113067-13 & Esquemático de la placa de la tarjeta SD \\
3113067-14 & Cara TOP de la PCB de la placa de la tarjeta SD\\
3113067-15 & Cara BOTTOM de la PCB de la placa de la tarjeta SD\\
3113067-16 & Vías de la PCB de la placa de la tarjeta SD\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Referencia y descripción de los planos del Apéndice A}
\label{planostable}
\end{table}

 \clearpage}  % prevent other material from being placed on this page
```

NOTE: I posted before for this same problem for figures and I tried aswking this there too once the image problem was solved, but I got the question closed, so I open a new one as I understand this is a different question.

Comment: Why using `\afterpage`? The other question has been closed with a reference to another question where the problem is solved.

Comment: But not for a table, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Tables or figures is just the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me.

```
\chapter{Esquemáticos y PCB}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{10cm}@{}}
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Referencia y descripción de los planos del Apéndice A}
\label{planostable}
\end{table}
```

It's quite difficult to understand why you're using `\afterpage` and `\clearpage` after `\chapter` which *will* push the float on the following page.